# get element based on class name - Cypress

Tags: cypress

I want to get the following element from the dom.

```
<span class="MuiBadge-badge MuiBadge-anchorOriginTopRightRectangle MuiBadge-colorError">5</span>
```

I'm looking for a simple syntax like:  `cy.contains('.MuiBadge-badge')`. I can pass the full list of classes but it is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more what you are expecting from the test ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should also be able to use `cy.get('[class*="MuiBadge-badge"]')`. The asterisk usually represents a wildcard, and indicates that, in this case, the class contains this string.

Answer (score 3):

You're close. You would just use the .get() command.

In your example, you could select based on one or more classes. Note for each class name you are selecting the period before the class.

For a single class: `cy.get('.MuiBadge-badge');`

For multiple classes: `cy.get('.MuiBadge-badge .MuiBadge-anchorOriginTopRightRectangle .MuiBadge-colorError');`

The documentation is here: https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/get#Syntax